# PlayFramework SQL Database error

Tags: sql, sql-server, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Am trying to use access SQL DataBase with Play Framework, my application.conf contains :

```
   db.default.driver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
   db.default.url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://server_ip:1433/db-name"
   db.default.user="user"
   db.default.password="password"
```

and i have the  jtds jar file in the lib folder with the  play dependencies add to my Build.sbt file

and i still got the following error:
**Cannot connect to database [default].**

can anyone help.

Comment: You shall paste more error message. Especially the reason why cannot connect to database

Comment: Create database first and restart your application.

Comment: i have the data base created and this is the only error message i got

Answer (score 0):

If you are tracking the tutorial project, you can see
you have to give your database name in your application.conf file as:

```
db=postgres://user:pwd@host/database
```

In the past I got over the problem doing:

```
db=postgres://humungus:humungus@localhost/yourdatabasename
```

It worked for me.